# Twitter App not taking localhost and 127.0.0.1 as CallbackUrl

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am developing an Application on my localhost environment. Where I want to implement Twitter OAuth functionality in PHP. So I just went on dev.twitter.com and was trying to create an app but its not allowing me to pass `Callback URL` as `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

**1) Firstly I tried as localhost**

[image: Callback URL as localhost]

**2) Then I tried as localhost/demoproject**

[image: Callback URL as localhost with projectname]

**3) After I tried IP with project name**

[image: Callback URL as IPAddress with projectname]

But its taking it as a invalid callback/url format.

[image: Error]

Is there any way to deal with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

For localhost, use the following URLs in your dev.twitter.com application setup:

```
Website URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/twitter/oauth
Callback URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/twitter/oauth
```

And don’t worry, these are just placeholders, as long as your code sends the correct callback URL when it connects, things ought to work...

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a Valid URL only for developing Twitter app. Local testing it should be `http://127.0.0.1/folder_name`.

If both are not working, Hope this [topic](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5749) will help you.

Comment: I tried with `http://127.0.0.1/folder_name`. You can check my 3rd point in my post

Comment: I heared while registering an app in twitter it will ask callback url

Answer (score 0):

[Former Twitter Employee's Answer - see @episod's post](https://twittercommunity.com/t/why-cant-i-use-localhost-as-my-oauth-callback/708#post_5)

It turns out that adding a localhost address is not what you should be doing for development anyhow.  In the OAuth handshake, your app should provide a callback URL which will override the configured URL on the config page.

The solution is to simply add any URL there as a placeholder.